# How to perform rake after a create action?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, controller, rake

I need to perform a rake after a create action.

I have a .rake in my lib/tasks dir. How do I tell rails to run the rake after a create action?

Comment: You can probably call system("rake mytask") in after_create callback, but I must warn you, that running rake is very cpu and memory intensive. See if you can do it in some other way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call from your controller

```
system("rake_path your_command_here")
```

after create action. The system call returns true if successful.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
def create
  system "rake apn:notifications:deliver"
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can call from your controller using two ways

```
 1. system("rake_path your_command_here")
 2. `rake_path your_command_here`
```